# Set timelimit when executing script

Tags: php

I would like to know if its possible to set a timelimit/timeout to a script in php..

ex: I have a script to update my avatar, and I would like to know if it's possible when a user tries to insert a LARGE file, if it's taking too long, show an message or redirect to another page saying `try to insert an smaller file`

Comment: Define `LARGE` file? What is your size?

Comment: actually doesn't matter, my `LARGE` means, taking too long, just that, if its taking more than 10 seconds to upload, show an message or redirect

Comment: I strongly suggest that you should check the image size to handle this. Time is not accurate and enough data to redirect user. You can use the [getimagesize function](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.getimagesize.php) on php.

Comment: What may take 10 seconds may take 1 second depending on the user's upload speed. Time is not an accurate constraint here. You need to go with a file `size` limit for this stuff.

Comment: But, think with me guys.. If the user tries to upload an large .mp4 file (even i'm just allow .jpg .png and .jpeg files) the .mp4 will load until 100% and just after that will give an message `files allowed: ...` FOR THAT i wanted this... If they try to upload a large file, "kill" it after 10 seconds

Answer (score 3):

you can use the PHP function `set_time_limit($seconds)`

Answer (score 2):

There are config settings for PHP that measure the file size:
max_file_upload
max_upload_size

Update those to the maximum file size you'll accept and then PHP will do the rest.

Comment: BUT the thing is: if the user tries to upload an .mp4 file, the file will load until 100% and just after that will show an message saying an error.. My ideia was after 5 or 10 seconds after it (to not take a lot of time loading the file) just redirect the user to other page