# Failing to execute long running python script from php mac

Tags: php, python

I'm calling a python script to execute using php exec. The python script has a ncbiwww online blast method which takes more than 30 seconds to execute. I edited the `maximum_execute_time` in php.ini to 720 seconds.
Short time running python scripts are giving me output (I'm writing output to a json file), long running script is failing to give me output (no file written). My code is as follows:

**blast.php:**

```php
if (!empty($_POST['inputFromHtml'])) {
        $python = (exec("path-to-python-script/pythonScript.py &")); //**this is not executing**
        $array = array('inputFromHtml' => $variable);
        $fp = fopen('path-to-json-file/inputWrittenToJson.json', 'w'); //**this part works**
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
        fclose($fp);


        if ($python) {
            echo "Successful! <br />"; //this not executing
            // echo "Accession number: " . $variable . "<br>"; //**not echoing**
            echo $python; // **not outputting**

            $URL = "http://localhost/folder/blast.php"; //**page refreshing but appears to be waiting for output forever**

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href = '{$URL}';</script>";
            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $URL . '">'; 
        }
);
    } elseif (alternative code) {
        other methods
    }
```

I have searched several fora but no solution yet. My python script executes fully if I use the terminal (mac user).

**My python script:**

```py
import json, xmltodict, pprint, datetime, os, sys,
from flask import Flask,
from flask import request,
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

with open('path-json-file-with-my-variable/inputWrittenToJson.json') as json_file:
    acc_dict = json.load(json_file)
    acc = acc_dict['accessionNumber']
    print(acc)

result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nr", acc, format_type="XML")

data = xmltodict.parse(result_handle.read(), process_namespaces=True)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

with open('path-to-save-blast-output/blastOutput.json', 'w') as fp:
    pp.pprint(json.dump(genomeData, fp))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set timelimit when executing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186175/set-timelimit-when-executing-script)